# next.js dynamic import of local images without using the public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, import

I have names of images in the database that I want to dynamically import e.g. `[id].png`.
I want to import them from the link `app/_assets/img/[id].png`

The problem is that 'import' works statically, and I don't want to make these images public. I also care about the images utilizing the potential of the Image component and not overloading the server.

I've heard that it can be done using the `require` function, but I don't want to load the images from the server on every render. I want them to be cached.